# Expansion of $\Gamma(-\epsilon)$ and $\Gamma(1-\epsilon)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, calculus

I'm currently trying to do some loop calculations in QFT and have come to a point where I need to expand a product of [$\Gamma$-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Let $\epsilon$ be the parameter introduced in the $\overline{\text{MS}}$-regularization scheme that we want to let go to zero in the end. I'm aware of the usual expansion
$$
\Gamma(\epsilon)\approx \frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_{EM}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\Gamma(-1+\epsilon)\approx -1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_{EM}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon).
$$
What I need are slightly different variations of this, i.e. $\Gamma(-\epsilon)$ and $ \Gamma(1-\epsilon)$.

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1009/1009.5313.pdf) there exists an identity
$$\Gamma(-x)=-\frac{\Gamma(1-x)}{x},
$$
which would solve the problem. Unfortunately, I can't find another source that confirms this identity or that states what the contraints on $x$ are, if there are any... Does someone know of a proof of this or another source?

Comment: Do you have to prove the identities? Why not just put them into a CAS system and expand it in the small parameter $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Triatticus I don't necessarly need a proof.. At the end of the day, I just need to expand $\Gamma(-\epsilon)$ and $\Gamma(1-\epsilon)$. The only CAS I'm familiar with is Mathematica, but I usually found it rather difficult to do expansion of $\Gamma$ in it, so I thought it might be easier to use the above identity and do it by hand...

Comment: Really? The code is straightforward it's just Series[Gamma[x],{x, x_0,n}]. Where you put the value of $x_0$ and the order needed $n$.

Comment: @Triatticus I haven't really tried it with this case, so it might just be as easy as you suggest. I will give it a shot as soon as I am at uni (where I have access to a working Mathematica version).

Comment: The expressions you give suggest that you are content to drop $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ terms. In that case, $\Gamma(1 - \epsilon) = 1 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ is obvious.

Comment: This identity (not in exactly that form) is proven on the Wikipedia page on the gamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)$ is the easier one since we know that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ so $\Gamma(1)=0!=1$; so
$$\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)=1-\varepsilon\Gamma'(1).$$
The derivative of Gamma function is related to another special function called *$\psi$ function* defined by
$$\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=(\ln\Gamma(x))'.$$
By consulting some tables you will find that
$$\psi(1)=-\gamma;$$
so
$$\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)=1+\gamma\varepsilon.$$

While for $\Gamma(-\varepsilon)$, the formula you found in other's paper is nothing else but basic properties of Gamma function
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z).$$
Or you can understand this from *Euler's reflection formula*
$$\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}.$$
A proof for this formula can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).